# How to correctly annotate type for operator.gt?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy, type-hinting

I've got the following piece of code:

```
from typing import List
import operator


class A:

    def __init__(self, x: int) -> None:
        self.x = x

    def __gt__(self, other: "A") -> int:
        return 0 if self.x > other.x else -1


lst: List[A] = []
sorted(lst, key=operator.gt)
```

Now the issue is that `mypy` will complain about:

> Argument "key" to "sorted" has incompatible type "Callable[[Any, Any], Any]"; expected "Optional[Callable[[A], Any]]"

Where I'm assuming that `operator.gt` was obviously annotated like that.

My question is, how can I annotate in such a way that it's also explicit that `lst` is a `List[A]`, and that `mypy` will not complain about `operator.gt`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `mypy` and everything with the signature of `key` and `operator.gt`: The operator takes two arguments (the two things to compare) whereas `key` takes a single argument with which to convert elements.

In other words: the problem is not `A` vs. `Any`, but rather `[foo]` vs `[foo, foo]`.

What are you trying to achieve with this key function?

Comment: Ah I see, I was misusing `operator.gt`. This is why type-hinting is good I guess.